# dojo dijit client side validation onchange

Tags: validation, client-side, dojo, onchange

So I followed the example in the Dojo - Using the Dojo JavaScript Library to Build Ajax Applications to add server-side validation to the username validationtextbox field on my form. Basically I added a usernameOnChange function that submitted an xhrGet request, the xhrGet returns JSON and is handled by the usernameValidationHandler.

It works great, but the usernameValidationHandler only sets the tooltip display message to an error. It doesn't set the field to be invalid and thus the user can still submit the form. How do I set the field to be invalid so the form won't submit?

```
    <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" size="20" 
       dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
       trim="true" 
       required="true" 
       onChange="userNameOnChange"
       regExp="\w+"
       invalidMessage="User name is required"
    />

function userNameOnChange() { 
    var userName = dijit.byId("userName").getValue();
    if (userName == "") {
        return;
    }        
    dojo.xhrGet( { 
        url: "validateUserName.jsp?userName=" + userName,
        handleAs: "json",
        handle: userNameValidationHandler
    });
}

function userNameValidationHandler(response) {
    dijit.byId("userName").displayMessage();

    if (!response.valid) {
     var errorMessage = "User name already taken";
        // Display error message as tooltip next to field
        dijit.byId("userName").displayMessage(errorMessage);
        // HOW DO I SET THE FIELD TO BE INVALID NOW???
    }
}
```

Comment: you could use dojo.connect to connect the 'onChange' method in the widget directly to a function which would preserve the 'this' reference.  That way you wouldn't have to do the id lookup and be locked to a single widget instance.

Answer (score 3):

It seems I was having the same issues when I used the validation method (validator) for the control. I think the issue is with the nature of the xhrGet method as it is asychronous, so the method for determining if value is valid returns before the query is complete. Anyways, this is what I did to get it working. If there is another way, hopefully someone can post.

```js
 dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");

 function validateUsername(value, constraint) {
   // I believe the whole reason you have to hack at control to get it to 
   // display an error is due to the nature of the xhrGet call. Since the
   // call is being made asychronously, the method would have already
   // returned a result to the html control before query has finished.
   // Therefore you have to do the extra method calls below. Also note
   // that when the form goes for submission, it calls each controls validator
   // method again! Meaning it will query the webpage again.
   var loginID = dijit.byId("user_login");

   var bNoNameFound = ("Error" == loginID.get("state")) ? false : true;

   if ("" == loginID.value) {
     // for some required=true is not kicking in, so we are forcing it.
     bNoNameFound = false;
   } else {
     if (false == loginID._focused) {
       console.log("Checking username...");
       dojo.xhrGet({
         url: "functions/does_user_exist.php?user_login=" + value,
         handleAs: 'text',
         content: {
           l: value
         },
         timeout: 10000,
         load: function(data) {
           if (1 == data) {
             // setting the state to error since the username is already taken
             bNoNameFound = false;
             loginID.set("state", "Error");
             loginID.displayMessage("The username is already taken...");
             // used to change the style of the control to represent a error
             loginID._setStateClass();
             console.log("Invalid username");
           } else {
             bNoNameFound = true;
             loginID.set("state", "");
             loginID.displayMessage("");
           }
         }
       });
     }
   }

   return bNoNameFound;
 }
```

```html
<input dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" value="" minSize="1" maxSize="25" tabindex="10" required="true" trim="true" regExp="\w+" validator=validateUsername />
```

Note: I also tried using "sync" in the xhrGet parameters as well. It also had issues (aside from the obvious of locking the control until query is done)...

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass the widget to override the [validator](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3/dijit.form.ValidationTextBox.validator) method.  Perhaps chain up, if you want the base functionality, then, if the result is true, run your own test with the getXhr and return the result.

[An example at dojocampus](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/ValidationTextBox-tricks) just clobbers the validator method.  That might also work, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Could you give me an example? Is there a standard way of doing this type of validation? Why isn't there a property I can set to indicate the field is invalid? It seems like an odd example to check the field onChange, but not make it invalid.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you override the validation method instead of hooking onChange, actually.  My comment above was academic.  I'll add a link to an example I found above.